# Creating a nesting layout with a fixed column that's scroll able

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, bulma

I'll try my best to explain this as clearly as I can. I'm also using the Bulma CSS framework if it matters. So the layout I'm trying to create is this.

[image]

I created a working version that can be [seen in action here](https://i.gyazo.com/6a401b8636fba2a928b7c4421e94dcba.mp4)

However, in the working example the vh/px of the scrollable box is fixed to a certain amount and I'm using tiles from the Bulma CSS framework. I tried using columns and the same outcome occurred. If I was to not make it a fixed amount, it'll just extend past the screen, but I want it to fit the entire screen regardless of the size and the only scrollable part should be the green box I've showed above. Also, the box may not even have enough content to become scrollable in some cases, and in that case I would still like it to fill up the rest of the height with the box even if it's going to be empty.

[As you can see here](https://i.gyazo.com/114860eed12e00adc34e066c59b9ef49.mp4), if the height isn't explicitly set, it'll keep going past the screen, but if it's properly set it will work as intended. I'm wondering how I can make this height fill the space properly no matter how it's resized and etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should set the height property on the wrapper of the content and set the `overflow: scroll;` Then all of the contents will be the height you set and have scrollable content.

Comment: If I set the wrapper as overflow: scroll; all that would make is the entire section will become scrollable, but I just want that small green box to be scrollable so I don't think this quite fixes it

Comment: Im saying to wrap that section in a parent div and set overflow:scroll on that. So its not wrapping the entire sections.